# How to create a column with varchar of 30 using Knex js?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, knex.js

I am using Knex js with my node application and I need to have some columns with varchar 330 and 50, but I couldn't find any resource explaing how to achieve that using Knex.

I need something like
`table.string("userName").notNullable().varchar(30);`

Answer (score 3):

You can define the length by passing a second argument to the .string method specifying the wanted length.

```
string — table.string(name, [length])
```

Reference:  http://knexjs.org/#Schema-string